Understanding coroutine and iscoroutinefunction in inspect python
Given a class which has synchronous methods but call asynchronous methods inside another class. When I am trying to call a synchronous method in a sync class, I am still getting coroutine was never awaited. Following is an example script
from time import perf_counter as timer
from functools import wraps
from typing import Union
from inspect import iscoroutinefunction


from dscommonutil.logger.basic import Logger

log = Logger("abc", ".")
log.start()


def timeit(task: str, logger: Union[Logger, str] = "log"):
    def _timeit(func):
        nonlocal logger
        if isinstance(logger, Logger):
            obj_check = False
        elif isinstance(logger, str):
            obj_check = True
        else:
            raise ValueError(
                f"{logger} needs to be a valid logging object or"
                " an attribute of args[0] parameter."
            )

        @wraps(func)
        async def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
            nonlocal logger
            start_time = timer()
            if obj_check and (
                isinstance(args[0], object) and getattr(args[0], logger, False)
            ):
                logger = getattr(args[0], logger)

            if iscoroutinefunction(func):
                value = await func(*args, **kwargs)
            else:
                value = func(*args, **kwargs)
            logger.info_metric(
                    f"Time elapsed in {task}",
                    round(timer() - start_time, 2)
                )
            return value
        return wrapper
    return _timeit


class Async:
    def __init__(self):
        self.log = log

    @timeit(task="running sync function")
    def sync(self, arg):
        self.log.info_print("Inside Synchronous Function")
        return arg
    
    @timeit(task="running async function")
    async def caller(self, arg):
        self.log.info_print("Inside Asynchronous Function")
        value = await self.sync(arg)
        return value


class Client:
    def __init__(self):
        self.log = log

    @timeit(task="random func")
    def func(self):
        self.log.info_print("Inside func from client")
        return "Hello"


    def main(self):
        print(self.func())

        a = Async()
        return a.caller("abc")



if __name__ == '__main__':
    import asyncio
    c = Client()
    asyncio.run(c.main())


Note: dscommonutil is some internally developed library for logging, this is purely synchronous.
The problem is mainly associated when calling self.func() and it says RuntimeWarning: coroutine 'Client.func' was never awaited.
Can anyone please help understand what would be an appropriate way of calling the functions here, and how can I make the sync calls without using await?
The code works if I simply add
value = await self.func()
print(value)

I wanted to understand more on the asynchronous functionality of Python, as to my understandig this should not have been detected as coroutine by inspect.iscoroutinefunction, but somehow it's doing so.

I tried to run your code and it seems the problem is with async def wrapper(*args, **kwargs). Since it is an async decorator, it expects you to await it, even though it is wrapping a sync method. You might consider making the wrapper synchronous to support both sync and async methods. This example might help you.
def timeit(func):
    def _timeit(func):
        nonlocal logger
        if isinstance(logger, Logger):
            obj_check = False
        elif isinstance(logger, str):
            obj_check = True
        else:
            raise ValueError(
                f"{logger} needs to be a valid logging object or"
                " an attribute of args[0] parameter."
            )
     @functools.wraps(func)
     def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
        nonlocal logger
        start_time = timer()
        _timeit(func)

        if obj_check and (
           isinstance(args[0], object) and getattr(args[0], logger, False)
        ):
        logger = getattr(args[0], logger)

       if not asyncio.iscoroutinefunction(func):
           return func(*args, **kwargs)
       else:
           async def tmp():
                 return (await func(*args, **kwargs))
           return tmp()
   return wrapper


I tried this, but what happens is, when the Async.caller is calling Async.sync, it doesn't wait to complete sync and the log prints (Time elapsed in completing async), which means async is already completed.

The example I provided it is kinda the only way I know how to create a decorator which supports both async and sync methods.Can you elaborate more on what you mean by "it doesn't wait to complete the sync and the log prints"?

In main, when I call a.caller, notice that it uses timeit decorator. Now it should finish only when self.sync inside a.caller has executed. But log statement of timing a.caller runs and finishes before a.sync finishes. Following is the log trace
'message': '{'type': 'metric', 'key': 'Time elapsed in running async function', 'valueMetric': 0.0}'
'message': 'Inside Asynchronous Function'
'message': 'Inside Synchronous Function'

See how Time elapsed in Async already run even before being in synchronous function

So it means that the original problem was fixed with the example I provided. If yes can you append question with the updated code. It is difficult to understand which problem you have now without looking at the code. I have an idea what might be wrong but can't be sure for now.

Issue not resolved yet, the function still fails with error saying tmp is never awaited at the end.

RuntimeWarning: coroutine 'Client.func' was never awaited was the original error which you encountered. Since you are getting a new error seems there is some progress. To move further please update the intial question with a new code.
